# Azure AutoML returning scoring probabilities like in Azure ML Studio Webservice

Tags: azure, machine-learning, scoring, automl

Is it possible to become the scoring probabilities from a deployed Azure AutoML classification model like in Azure Ml Studio Webservice?

I can't see any settings for this. Can I extend somehow the finished model, before it is deployed?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the AutoML model:

```
best_run, fitted_model = automl_run.get_output()
class_prob = fitted_model.predict_proba(X_test)
```

For each sample row, the max probability is the predicted class

Further info/exmaple here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-configure-auto-train